# Laravel 5 - Cannot declare self-referencing constant 'X' in router.php

Tags: php, laravel

So today I tried to work on my project and randomly got this error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Working in Laravel 5.

Comment: You need to show some code.

Comment: A little research seems to indicate that's an internal error in PHP, possibly memory related. If working with mod_php, try restarting your web server. Otherwise, there's almost nothing in your question to go on.

Comment: @zerkms It is reporting from the Laravel core files.

Comment: I see, Laravel core files === cannot cause any problems. How about you ask laravel developers then?

Comment: After 1-2 hours of research the issue if fixed when I run the following command.
"service php-fpm restart"

Luckily, I did not attempt to ask the laravel developers.

Comment: It's not a solution but a workaround: the problem did not disappear but was *temporarily mitigated*. It's like trying to "treat" a broken finger with panadol. But good luck anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following command solved the issue.

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Hope this help someone else.